# How to read hashed password while login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've used this 
http://jphellemons.nl/post/Easy-generate-SHA1-in-AspNet

To hash password that has been created while registering, but when I try to login it doesn't let me.

How do I make it the hash read as a normal text that has been putted into form before it was submited and converted into hash?

@Edit.

Though I can login with hashed password when I use the whole hash text..but it is not what I want D:

@edit2

this is how login thing looks like

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM users
                            WHERE login = @username
                            AND pass = @password";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox_Login.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox_Password.Text);

        con.Open();
       }
```

Comment: Are passwords saved plain or hashed on database ?

Comment: @CihanYakar   This is example how one of the password looks like after the hashing   D561AAD4326B6A3C50143908E22A2252336CB9B1   and it is set as a varchan in the table. But lets say that the hashed passowrd was "potato", when I try to login I can't use potato but I have to use the hash instead to login xD

Comment: @Harugawa - See my answer. You'll take "potato" and hash it on login for the sake of the comparison with the stored password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashing is one way. You cannot convert it back to the text you started with (generally speaking of course).

It sounds like when you login, you're missing a step to hash the text that was put into your login and compare to the stored hash. You mentioned that using the hash text in the login form works, but if you simply hash the login password text and use that for the authentication/comparison instead, you'll get the intended results.

If you hash `TextBox_Password.Text` and then pass it as a parameter instead of passing the text directly, you should get the result you're after. Although you'll want to do a little research and implement a salt on your hashes eventually.

Comment: Added the login code I'm using, beside the part when I create the sessions and stuff

Comment: @Harugawa - You'll need to pass the hashed version of `TextBox_Password.Text`. That way you'll be passing a hash equal to what is stored in the DB.

Comment: I see, I managed to do it. So, hash is kind of global thing? Cause now I managed to login with the potato ;o by adding hashing to login page

Comment: It would kind of depend on your definition of "global". After hashing, basically you'll have to hash all text you plan on comparing with that hash. Never try to get the original text back, that defeats the purpose of the security hashing gives you. Glad you got it working though! :)

Comment: @CihanYakar makes a good point. Since hashes are **intended** to be irreversible, it makes your site much safer if a hacker cannot reverse the hash and get the password. Of course, you'll want to eventually do more to your hashing, such as using salts (which is a whole different topic by itself), which causes even the same password to hash very differently. So if a hacker were to figure out the hash for "potato", another user with that password would have a different hash. It's quite an interesting topic.

Comment: There is an interesting overview I read a while ago. Here is the link. Definitely read it at least once! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right

Comment: @DangerZone Thanks, gonna read it asap. And yeah, that is what I meant with that hashes are "kind of global". That other user with potato would have same hash x_ x? If im not wrong

Comment: @Harugawa - With your current implementation, yes, all of your users with "potato" have the same hash. This is not too bad for a start, but you'll definitely want to add a salt. The article I mentioned details how easy it is to reverse many non-salted hashed. Large dictionaries exist and make this very easy (and unsafe). Adding a salt makes these hacking attempts much less effective, even if a hacker got their hands on all of the hashes in your DB. With no salt, you should assume they will be able to look up any password in their dictionary with ease.

Comment: @DangerZone Thanks again for help :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the hash is that it's really easy to encrypt and really hard to decrypt. The way to login is to run the attempted password through the same hash algorithm and then compare that hash with the stored hash for the user. You should never be able to read the stored hash as plain text.